# To many ImageView, out of memory

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap, imageview

I am pretty new to dealing with images and bitmap. I do have one layout that contains 19 ImageViews. They are all inn a scroll view. But when I try to load it, does it tell me that I am out of memory. Each file is 36 kb. So not huge.

This is the code I am using.:

```
  //Load av bilder seng 1
    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_1);
    ImageView im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng1);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);


    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_2);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng2);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_3);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng3);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_4);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng4);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_5);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng5);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_6);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng6);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_7);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng7);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_8);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng8);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_9);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng9);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_10);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng10);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_11);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng11);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_12);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng12);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_13);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng13);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_14);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng14);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_15);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng15);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_16);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng16);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

    h1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sengbilde_17);
    im = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.iseng17);
    im.setImageBitmap(h1);

Bitmap h1, h2, h3, h4, h5;
Resources res;
```

Is this the right way or is there some other more clever way to do this?

Bitmap h1, h2, h3, h4, h5;
    Resources res;

Edit!

I dont know why, but when I did make the images smaller did it all work. I used this code to help me out:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(int id){
    //Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, o);
    //BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

    //The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale=1;
    while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale*=2;

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize=scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, o2);
}
```

Comment: You could be using setImageResource() instaed of setImageBitmap to save a line of code. I'm not sure if you should be calling recycle() on your bitmaps after applying them to image views, but you don't need to worry about that if you apply the resources directly.

Comment: What drawable folder are your images stored in? If you put a small image in the drawable or drawable-mdpi folder, it will be loaded with much higher dimensions on a modern xdpi device, and therefore use orders of magnitude more memory than the original file (I think). Also, a jpg image is a small file, but still uses 32 bits per pixel once it's loaded as a bitmap.

Comment: I am putting them in the drawable folder. I did read some where that ImageView call recyle by it self. And if I try to use recyle. The program crashes.  The images loads fine if I use up to 11. But more images than that cant it handel. Is there some Smart or tricky way to load images in Android to make sure you get them all?

Comment: Try moving them into `drawable-nodpi` so they don't scale up. Just quick math, a typical 512x512 jpg image could take up about 36KB, but if it's loaded from the `drawable` or `drawable-mdpi` folder on an xdpi device, it will load as a 1024x1024 bitmap (4MB). But still I wouldn't expect 11 4MB images to be too much memory. Hmm.

Comment: I did try that, but it did not work. So I am not sure what the next step is.

Comment: You may simply be loading too many images. What dimensions are they, and what device are you testing on? See here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html On some devices, apps are only allowed to use up to 16MB.

Comment: They are 640x480. I am testing them on SAMSUNG Galaxy SIII mini. I have been reading the tutorial and tried the most of it. I am going to try to save it as a catch to the phones SDCard and see if that work.

Comment: Yeah, that device I think only allows 16MB per app, and 11 images at that size uses about 13MB. The rest may be getting used up by the rest of your UI and other temporary stuff in going on in onCreate.

Comment: I would recommended you can put all images into assets folder and then fetch the image one by one and scaled down it(if you want) and then load these images to your ImageView. Because i have been worked such type of app in android and stores up to 50 MB(total size) images into assets and used it.